# Horizontal navigation all across the navigation bar

Tags: android

Hello Friends I am using wireless Bluetooth for this for selecting action..
what is my issue..when i move cursor from drag down it works fine for selection but when i horizontally moves cursor it not working...can anyone please help me out from this

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE: {
            this.mTimerTaskHover = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    Runnable docScreenRunnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            playKeyTone();

                        }
                    };
                    runOnUiThread(docScreenRunnable, "homeScreeImageView");
                }
            };

        }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT: {
            // this.mTimerHover.cancel();

            if (this.mTimerTaskHover != null) {
                this.mTimerTaskHover.cancel();
                this.mTimerTaskHover = null;
                this.mTimerHover.cancel();
                this.mTimerHover.purge();
                this.mTimerHover = null;
                this.mTimerHover = new Timer(); // if timer was cancelled
                                                // starts it again
            }
```